# Use Systick on samd21e15b

Tags: c, timer, samd21

I'am working with Systick for the first time with an samd21e15b, so my objective is to be able to count time between delay for example. So here is what I've try to do

```
SysTick->CTRL = 0;
SysTick->LOAD = 0x7A11FFul;
SysTick->VAL = 0;
SysTick->CTRL = 0x5;
while(SysTick->VAL == 0);
uint32_t start = SysTick->VAL;
delay_ms(1000);
uint32_t stop = SysTick->VAL;
uint32_t volatile temps = start - stop;
```

So I set `SysTick->LOAD = 0x7A11FFul` beceause my CPU run at 8Mhz and I want 1s tick, so coming from this math

> N = (SysTick delay time / System Clock Period ) - 1
>
> =(SysTick delay time * System Clock Frequency) - 1
>
> = (1s * 8MHz) -  1 = 8M - 1 = 7,999,99

So if my cpu runs at 8MHz I have one cpu cycle every 125ns is it right? But if I inspect `temps` variable I have a value of `311` after delay of 1s and I don't understand this value

Comment: 1) 8M - 1 = 7,999,99**9**. 2) You can use decimals, even constant expressions like `8000000ul - 1` to make your intent clear. 3) `start - stop` looks wrong to me. In which direction does SysTick count, up or down? 4) Please [edit] your question providing a [example] for those who can use the same compiler and hardware.

Comment: Don't write magic numbers to registers such as `SysTick->CTRL = 0x5;`. If I have to read your code with my nose stuck in the manual, your code needs to be fixed. See [How to access a hardware register from firmware?](https://electrical.codidact.com/posts/276290)

Answer (score 1):

Some issues:

- On SAM parts you first have to configure the general clock settings and the various "GCLK" options, but assuming that's done and you've indeed got a clock running at 8MHz, then one tick is indeed 125ns.
- The `LOAD` register wants `delay / frequency - 1`, so if we for example want 1s then 1 / 125x10<sup>-9</sup> = 8x10<sup>6</sup>.

  Thus: `SysTick->LOAD = 8000000u - 1`. We want self-documenting code in normal base 10 decimal. No mysterious hex magic numbers. And document where you got this number from in comments!

  I'm not sure if it makes sense to set SysTick to use 1s though - I always set it to 1ms. Or otherwise I'm not sure what will happen to code like `delay_ms(1000);`.
- `while(SysTick->VAL == 0);` I don't understand why you do this, you'll introduce a clock inaccuracy right there. The clock supposedly starts running soon as you enable it.

  Which again isn't done with "magic numbers" but named constants. Example using ASF and assuming external clock:

  ```
  SysTick->CTRL = SysTick_CTRL_CLKSOURCE_Msk | 
                  SysTick_CTRL_ENABLE_Msk;
  ```
- `start - stop` is wrong, clocks count upwards. You'll want `stop - start`.